# Как вывести сообщение в Makefile?

Tags: makefile

При сборке (обычно ядра, драйверов, модулей ядра) командой `make` можно увидеть (вместо команд на компиляцию) примерно такие строки:

```
    CC arch/arm/vdso/vdso-offset.c
    CAT arch/arm/boot/Image
    GZIP arch/arm/boot/zImage-dtb
```

Как вместо команд (типа `gcc -lcrypto main.c -o main`) выводить такого рода сообщения?

Comment: "Использовать `make` для сборки". КО.

Comment: эм, вы меня неправильно поняли. Команда ```make``` по дефолту выводит команды сборки. А как выводить вместо них такой текст?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не поверите, но если написать вот так

```
all:
       @echo "test"
```

то все будет. echo - просто выводит сообщение, а @ подавляет вывод собственно самой команды в консоль.

То есть, возле всех команда нужно добавить @, а также добавить echo (или любую другую команду, которая выводит в консоль!), которая распечатает нужное.

Но что делать, если лень добавлять собачку к каждой команде?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967105/suppress-echo-of-command-invocation-in-makefile

Первое - запускать make с параметром `-s`. Хороший способ, но немного неудобно.

Второе - просто заглушить вывод для нужных целей (взято с ответа по ссылке выше)

```
.SILENT: run
hi:
     echo "Hola!"
run:
     java myprogram
```

для цели `hi` будет только `Hola!`, для цели `run` - будет вывод как обычно.